# Outlook for mac (add-in) - body does not keep html properties when created with setSelectedDataAsync

Tags: macos, office365, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-for-mac

I'm trying to create an add-in on compose mode for Outlook in mac, and when I insert HTML to the body element, I have noticed there are no properties attached.

Example (simplified for the purpose of explanation):

```
var contents = "<br/> <a id=\"myelement" + MyElement+ "\" href=\"dev.office.com\"></a>";
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setSelectedDataAsync(contents, { coercionType: "html" });
```

becomes:

```
<br/>
<a href="dev.office.com" style="color: rgb(5, 99, 193); text-decoration: underline;">MyElement</a>
```

There is no id on above and a new style is being applied.
(Note that I can see this by saving the email as draft and then inspecting it on office 365)

Answer (score 1):

setSelectedDataAsync () modifying the HTML is a bug and has been reported to the concerned team. This shall be fixed ASAP.

In the meantime to check if the host is an outlook Mac, you may use the following API check 
    `office.context.platform`

if the above API does not work ( as its still being pushed to production and not available to all users) then you may parse the user agent to check the platform type . 
sample code

```
var
    ua = navigator.userAgent,
    browser = /Edge\/\d+/.test(ua) ? 'ed' : /MSIE 9/.test(ua) ? 'ie9' : /MSIE 10/.test(ua) ? 'ie10' : /MSIE 11/.test(ua) ? 'ie11' : /MSIE\s\d/.test(ua) ? 'ie?' : /rv\:11/.test(ua) ? 'ie11' : /Firefox\W\d/.test(ua) ? 'ff' : /Chrome\W\d/.test(ua) ? 'gc' : /Chromium\W\d/.test(ua) ? 'oc' : /\bSafari\W\d/.test(ua) ? 'sa' : /\bOpera\W\d/.test(ua) ? 'op' : /\bOPR\W\d/i.test(ua) ? 'op' : typeof MSPointerEvent !== 'undefined' ? 'ie?' : '',
    os = /Windows NT 10/.test(ua) ? "win10" : /Windows NT 6\.0/.test(ua) ? "winvista" : /Windows NT 6\.1/.test(ua) ? "win7" : /Windows NT 6\.\d/.test(ua) ? "win8" : /Windows NT 5\.1/.test(ua) ? "winxp" : /Windows NT [1-5]\./.test(ua) ? "winnt" : /Mac/.test(ua) ? "mac" : /Linux/.test(ua) ? "linux" : /X11/.test(ua) ? "nix" : "",
    mobile = /IEMobile|Windows Phone|Lumia/i.test(ua) ? 'w' : /iPhone|iP[oa]d/.test(ua) ? 'i' : /Android/.test(ua) ? 'a' : /BlackBerry|PlayBook|BB10/.test(ua) ? 'b' : /Mobile Safari/.test(ua) ? 's' : /webOS|Mobile|Tablet|Opera Mini|\bCrMo\/|Opera Mobi/i.test(ua) ? 1 : 0,
    tablet = /Tablet|iPad/i.test(ua),
    touch = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @JordanDavis , the platform checking section was given so that there can be some specific HTML handling if its a mac outlook scenario

Comment: Anyone happen to know where I can find the official status of this bug?  I am seeing the same now in Mac Office 365 Version 16.76.2